# ¿Cómo convertir una columna de objects a una columna de ints?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, inteligencia-artificial

un gran saludo. Estoy trabajando con Pandas. Estoy haciendo limpieza de datos. El csv que tengo son partidas del videojuego del League of Legends. Las dos columnas que necesito como prioridad son objects, son dos columnas de los nombres de los equipos. Equipo 1 y equipo 2 para ver los datos de las partidas. Las columnas son t1_playerid y t2_playerid. Hay 104 equipos diferentes, y necesito hacer graficas y demas con estas dos columnas, por lo que para operar con ellas necesito pasarlas a numeros (si son enteros mejor). He hecho esto pero me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tampoco me funciona con un to_numeric(). Puedo hacerlo con replace() pero tendria que hacer 104 dataframes diferentes y luego unirlo todo.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

@ECQuant, es la forma que veo de añadirte la imagen. Supongo que te refieres a esto. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando iteras sobre un Dataframe estás iterando sobre los nombres de las columnas. No estoy seguro de qué contiene tu `df` pero yo supongo que es un Dataframe. Entonces, ¿por qué estás usando un for? Simplemente tienes que reemplazar los valores de dos columnas.

De nuevo, no estoy seguro de cómo está construido tu Dataframe pero creo que lo que te funcionaría es:

```
dataset['t1_playerid'] = dataset['t1_playerid'].map(title_maping)
```

Comment: Es un dataset con 1012 filas por 33 columnas. He quitado el bucle poniendo la sentencia que me has dicho y nada, me sigue diciendo el mismo error. Es un dataset sin ningun nulo con valores flotantes, enteros y strings, pero nada fuera de lo normal.

Comment: Me parece raro que te aparezca el mismo error. Podrías mostrar el error completo y si es posible el código también?

Comment: Te recomiendo también que estudies bien el funcionamiento de pandas. Está construido para que en general no tengas que usar loops y puedas hacer las operaciones sobre toda la columna de una sola vez.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que tienes una columna en el DataFrame llamada `t1_playerid` que contiene los nombres de los equipos como strings.

Si quieres ponerle un label a cada equipo, puedes utilizar `LabelEncoder` de la siguiente manera:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoder = LabelEncoder()

dataset['team_labeled'] = encoder.fit_transform(dataset['t1_playerid'])
```

De esta manera haces un map automático